# JAXB unmarshalling class with two instances fo same object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have two classes:

```
public class Game {

protected int Id;
protected int gameNumber;
protected int roundId;
protected Player playerOne;
protected Player playerTwo;
protected int playerOneScore;
protected int playerTwoScore;
protected Round round;

@XmlIDREF
@XmlElement(name = "playerOne")
public Player getPlayerOne() {
    return playerOne;
}

public void setPlayerOne(Player playerOne) {
    this.playerOne = playerOne;
}
}

public class Player {

protected int Id;
protected String userName;
protected String eMail;
protected int points;
protected String firstName;
protected String lastName;
protected List<Game> games;    


@XmlElementWrapper(name = "Games")
@XmlElement(name = "Game")
public List<Game> getGames() {
    return games;
}

public void setGames(List<Game> games) {
    this.games = games;
}

}
```

Using JAXB how can I set the player one and player two objects within the Game to the correct object references?

When i import the XML into my program it doesn't add players to the correct game.

I tried using

```
 public void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller u, Object parent) {
    if (parent instanceof Player) {
        this.playerOne = (Player) parent;
    }

}
```

but the issue is that there are two objects.

Any suggestions?

Comment: how does your XML look?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/xMP4vEbg